# Semantic Duplicate rows in inner join same table [PostgreSQL]

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I want to join my table with itself to check rows that have similar value on a specific column, but I want to remove implicit duplicated rows i.e. by executing the following query :

```
SELECT a1.id, a2.id
FROM table_1 a1 
JOIN table_1 a2 
ON a1.column_x = a2.column_x 
AND a1.id <> a2.id ;
```

I obtained :

```
 id | id
----+-----
 28 | 27
 27 | 28
 47 | 48
 48 | 47
...
```

What I want to obtain is :

```
 id | id
----+-----
 28 | 27
 47 | 48
```

How can I achieve that please ?

Comment: `AND a1.id > a2.i`

Comment: What's the expected result if there's a (33, 34) row, but no (34, 33)?

Comment: Yes I should also display (33, 34)

Comment: The accepted answer will not return (33, 34).

Comment: I do not have this kind of situation. All of them are repeated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `>` or `<` rather than `<>`:

```
SELECT a1.id, a2.id
FROM table_1 a1 JOIN
     table_1 a2 
     ON a1.column_x = a2.column_x AND
        a1.id > a2.id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` functions to always return the smaller value in the first column, and the larger value in the second column. Do `SELECT DISTINCT` to avoid duplicates.

Will return "alone" rows as well, for example if there's a (33, 34) row, but no (34, 33) row.

```
SELECT DISTINCT least(a1.id, a2.id), greatest(a1.id, a2.id)
FROM table_1 a1 
JOIN table_1 a2 
    ON a1.column_x = a2.column_x 
   AND a1.id <> a2.id ;
```